# loading webview is always nil after disconnecting from tokbox session

Tags: ios, swift, webview, tokbox

I'm working on a native app that uses a webview for most of the functionality, and it uses tokbox video for native video communication. When I initially load the app, the webview loads fine (its created in interface builder).

When a person goes to the video page, I believe the tokbox API makes the webview nil. Once the video is over, I call `session.disconnect()` and try to reload my webview, but it keeps saying found nil while trying to unwrap optional.

The code that loads the webview looks like this:

```
func loadApp() {
    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
    let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    // this was added in hopes of initializing the webview again
    if webView == nil {
        webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view = webView
    }
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.frame = view.bounds
    webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
}
```

it keeps failing at `webView.delegate = self` and the instance variables show that webView is still nil even after the if condition.

#### EDIT

the webview was hooked by clicking control and dragging to the UIViewController and it looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

the `loadApp()` function is called in 2 places, first in `viewDidLoad()` where it works fine, but then after calling `session.disconnect()`, a tokbox callback delegate method is called:

```
func sessionDidDisconnect(_ session: OTSession) {
    print("The client disconnected from the OpenTok session.")
    loadApp()
}
```

this is the second time/place where `loadApp()` is called, and where it fails.

Comment: UIWebview returns nil if it can't be initialized so even if it goes through that if statement it still might be nil. Where are you calling this function?

Comment: Are you sure that your webView property is not declared as a weak property?

Comment: @TNguyen I'm updating the question with where I'm calling the function

Comment: @TNguyen ok will try that

Comment: @TNguyen this actually worked, so if you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @duxfox-- will do so that others may see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think webView should be set to nil when you have it setup as a `IBOutlet`. Try just having webView be `var webView: UIWebView?` a variable inside of the class and then instantiate it manually and adjust the constraints and position it accordingly.